# MYSQL case statment comparing string values incorrect outcome

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query with what should be a simple case statement in comparing two srting values and populating whichever is the greater value as follows:

```
SELECT
wca.bond.secid,
wca.bond.IssueAmount,
wca.bochg.NewOutValue,
case when wca.bond.IssueAmount >= wca.bochg.NewOutValue
     then wca.bond.IssueAmount ELSE wca.bochg.NewOutValue END AS IssueAmount2
from
wca.bond
INNER JOIN wca.bochg ON wca.bond.secid = wca.bochg.SecID
WHERE
bond.secid = 5955156;
```

The following output is produced:

[image: Table output]

As you can see from the output the case statment does snot seem to work as it should as I would expect to see 12200 as the value under IssueAmount2 as opposed to 7200. I thought it may be due to the fields being compared being different formats but I can confirm they are both Varchars having the same length 20.

Does anyone know why I'm having this issue?

Comment: Is because they're both varchar datatype.. that's the reason.

Comment: I just used Cast as INT on both fieldss in my case statement and works correctly now - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `VARCHAR()` datatype, it will compare the first character. If the first character is the same, it will compare the second character and continue the comparison until it found a difference. In your case, although it's obvious that 12200 is **more** than 7200, that's only true if we're comparing numbers. So, with varchar, this is what happen:

```
[7]200 = 7 is bigger than 1
[1]2200 = 1 is smaller than 7
```

So what you need is to convert the value into integer. Here's a suggestion to your current query:

```
SELECT
wca.bond.secid,
wca.bond.IssueAmount,
wca.bochg.NewOutValue,
case when wca.bond.IssueAmount+0 >= wca.bochg.NewOutValue+0
     then wca.bond.IssueAmount ELSE wca.bochg.NewOutValue END AS IssueAmount2
from
wca.bond
INNER JOIN wca.bochg ON wca.bond.secid = wca.bochg.SecID
WHERE
bond.secid = 5955156;
```

Add `+0` to the column in comparison to quickly make the column value identified as integer. You can also use [CONVERT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp) or [CAST()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp):

```
CONVERT(varchar_val1, SIGNED) >= CONVERT(varchar_val2, SIGNED)
...
or
CAST(varchar_val1 AS SIGNED) >= CAST(varchar_val2 AS SIGNED)
...
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b942928ca577f736cb8e338e0199d215)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation - it was very helpful. I previously tried to cast as decimal and thought it was resolved then noticed it wasn't. However trying one of your examples specifically:

`CAST(varchar_val1 AS SIGNED) >= CAST(varchar_val2 AS SIGNED)`

Solved the issue for me - I didnt know about signed. Thank you